# htaccess rewrite different folder url, two index files

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been searching for awhile now and haven't found anything that comes close to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Right now my URL's look like this:

```
www.website.com/something
```

which are using the root folder `/index.php`

Now I have created plugins within folders:

```
/plugins/PLUGINNAME/index.php
```

I want to be able to have URLs like:

```
www.website.com/plugins/PLUGINNAME/anything/iwant/here
```

which are all using `/plugins/PLUGINNAME/index.php` and not the root directory `index.php`.

Currently `www.website.com/plugins/PLUGINNAME/` works, but anything after `/PLUGINNAME/xxx` defaults to the `/index.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will strip off any characters that come after the plugin folder slash, like anything/iwant/here in your example. Make sure the end is `.+` and not `.*` or you'll go into an infinite redirect loop

```
RewriteRule ^plugins/([^/]+)/.+ /plugins/$1/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: also, put this rule ABOVE whatever rule you have that sends everything else to /index.php

Comment: remove R=301 if you do not want the actual url to be rewritten in the browser and only forward on the request behind the scenes

Comment: If I remove R=301, it gives me internal server error. But this line is placed at the bottom of my htaccess file. So far this answer is working, I just don't want it to show in the browser URL that it's being redirected

Comment: RewriteRule ^plugins/([^/]+)/.+ /plugins/$1/ [NC,L] throws a 500 error?

Comment: Yup. But only on links with /plugins/ in it. This is also now at the top of my .htaccess file:

Comment: can you check the error log and post the message related to the 500 error?

Comment: Sure, the error came up 7 times: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://website.com/admin

Comment: The .+ at the end of the match pattern should prevent that rule from infinite redirection... Do you have any other rules in your htaccess that target the plugins folder? I tried this rule on my server and didnt get any 500 error on non R=301 so there must be something else going on here

Comment: I do have a rule set for another path: RewriteRule ^admin/plugins /index.php [L], but even removing this still brings up issues with or without the R=301.

Comment: I solved it. I had to rename the path. I simply renamed "^plugins/([^.." to "^plugin/([..." and it worked fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem, glad you figured it out